# Can I use one DLL process per executable

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dll

I am using DLL to enable modding in my game. In Visual Studio linker I link DLL's .lib with executable. Everything works fine but problem comes with adding multiplayer. Since it is DLL it is just one process for whole Windows, if I'm not wrong. But I need "client.exe" and "server.exe" to run without sharing same DLL. I tried renaming DLL for "server.exe" but then in told me it can't load it because it still needs "unrenamed" DLL. How can i make one DLL for "client.exe" and one for "server.exe" without making them share the same which leads to errors? If I create copy of DLL and put it somewhere else, will it make any difference? From what i've read it's just dependent on name and not path(maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: What is the problem when it shares the dll? It shouldn't matter if it's technically the same memory page or not where the code is executed from... Client and server are still two different processes.

Comment: DLLs are not shared between multiple processes.  Multiple processes may use the same DLL *file* on disk, but each process loads *its own copy* of the DLL into memory. So, whatever errors you are getting are likely due to bugs inside the DLL's coding, not by the client and server processes sharing the same DLL file.

Comment: @CherryDT they share same memory, but i need them to have separate memories

Comment: @MichaeltLoL DLLs do not share memory with each other by default, you would have to explicitly set that up yourself, using shared segments, or memory mapping views, etc.  So far, all of your assumptions/expections seem to be wrong.  So, what is the ACTUAL PROBLEM you are having?

Comment: @RemyLebeau okay, thanks!

Comment: @MichaeltLoL They might share code (it depends) but they don't share data.  Each executable gets its own copy of that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i meant that executables share same memory, but you stated before that it has it's own copy so that solves everything(i hope)

Comment: It's a technical implementation detail that the memory with the code in it is shared (which is only the case until it gets modified, by the way). That shouldn't affect anything in your code. Your variables etc. are still independent, since the data segment is a different block of memory in each process in which the DLL is loaded.

Comment: @MichaeltLoL "*executables share same memory*" - no, they don't. Separate processes have their own separate address spaces for their memory usage. Multiple processes do not share memory. So again, what is the ACTUAL PROBLEM you are having with the client and server using the same DLL?

Comment: Thank you all! It's most likely error caused by me. I needed to know if they are shared between executables to prevent any errors related to this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau by "executables share same memory" i meant that DLL is same memory for both executables, i'm sorry i wrote it wrong

Comment: @MichaeltLoL "*DLL is same memory for both executables*" - no, it is not. That is what you seem to be misunderstanding.  There is NO SHARING of memory between the same DLL in separate processes, unless YOU setup your own shared memory yourself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know it's not, i was correcting my previous comment. I understand everything, don't worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DLL is a binary file which is composed of several sections. These sections can be divided into two types. One is not related to absolute address addressing, so it can be shared by multiple processes; the other is related to absolute address addressing, and each process must have its own copy for exclusive use.

The two categories of sections are already marked by the compiler and linker when compiling the DLL. Therefore, when loading the DLL, the loader knows which sections need only one copy in the physical memory address space for multiple processes to share (mapped to the memory logical address space of each process, so the logical address can be different); which sections must be The process uses its own private copy. This perfectly solves the DLL multi-process sharing problem.

Every process that loads the DLL maps it into its virtual address space. After the process loads the DLL into its virtual address, it can call the exported DLL functions.

The system maintains a per-process reference count for each DLL. When a thread loads the DLL, the reference count is incremented by one. When the process terminates, or when the reference count becomes zero (run-time dynamic linking only), the DLL is unloaded from the virtual address space of the process.

Like any other function, an exported DLL function runs in the context of the thread that calls it. Therefore, the following conditions apply:

- The threads of the process that called the DLL can use handles opened
  by a DLL function. Similarly, handles opened by any thread of the
  calling process can be used in the DLL function.
- The DLL uses the stack of the calling thread and the virtual address
  space of the calling process.
- The DLL allocates memory from the virtual address space of the
  calling process.

If you want to using Shared Memory in a Dynamic-Link Library, you could refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/using-shared-memory-in-a-dynamic-link-library).